# Лучший метод оценки производительности труда программиста?

Tags: работа, производительность

Вариант 1. Количество строк кода в единицу времени. Плохой вариант. Все равно что измерять готовность самолета по его массе. Не учитывает китайский стиль.

Вариант 2. Работает/не работает. Слишком примитивно, не учитывает оптимизацию. Бомбейская школа программистов была здесь.

Вариант 3. Программист или его коллега сами оценивает работу друг друга исходя из собственного опыта. Зависит от программиста. Не объективно, но может принести результат или дело кончится холиваром.

Вариант 4. Оценка бесполезна для процесса и не стоит тратить на нее время.

Вариант 5. Быстрая микроценка проделанной за день работы. Не дает общей картины.

Кто каким образом делает это? Я использую вариант 5 + вариант 1 без учета копипаста, китайского кода и с учетом комментариев, получается около 5-20 кБайт в день в зависимости от части над которой идет работа. Какие еще есть варианты?

Comment: готовый продукт в нужные сроки - самая лучшая оценка производительности

Comment: Не надо путать производительность и уровень работы. Производительность - это как раз количественная оценка, которую можно легко формализовать: количество кода в день, скорость разработки. А вот качество создаваемого кода... Может плотность багов (количество багов на строчку кода)?

Comment: Как по мне программиста нельзя оценить таким образом. Собственно я придерживаюсь четвертого пункта. Первый пункт по определению не адекватен т.к. за день можно написать как 500 строк декларативного кода, так и реализовать в 100 строк какой-то довольно сложный и важный алгоритм.

Вообще, как я заметил, у многих программистов есть большая проблема вида - "блин, Вася пупкин знает( умеет ) что-то намного больше( лучше ) меня - поэтому я ни на что не гожусь", так вот - нельзя измерять всех одни мерилом.

PS: на мой взгляд действительно адекватно оценить вашу продуктивность может только ваша команд

Comment: Такое уже обсуждали: http://hashcode.ru/questions/46248/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B

Comment: @igumnov, Вы пишете

    получается около 5-20 кБайт в день

немало. Ради интереса посмотрел у себя. За 2 дня (как раз только код на Си) 7698 байт 446 строк.
Получается длина строки 17.26

Интересно, в строках у Вас сколько?

Comment: @avp Тут все зависит от части, так проект весьма сложен, кросс-платформенный 3D движок промышленного масштаба. Сегодня писал часть по конвертации текстовой 3D модели в формат движка. Там нету вызовов WinAPI, чисто алгоритмическая проблема, поэтому около 400 строк получилось. Если есть вызовы WinAPI(например при работе с консолью так как её интерфейс реализован с помощью двух окон класса "EDIT"), приходится по долгу копаться в MSDN и производительность катастрофически падает до 200-300 строк. Среднюю длину к сожалению не считал, позже проверю.

Comment: Еще иногда возникает ситуация когда одна маленькая ошибка ищется часа полтора и во время её поиска естественно количество кода сильно не меняется. Обычно это что-то связанное с неправильным использованием указателей. За это время в проект в лучшем случае добавляется код для вывода дебаг информации который потом комментируется.

Comment: @Spectre Вы идеалист!

Comment: @igumnov Как-то больно много, если честно.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать. Еще нужно учесть то что там все находится в зачаточном состоянии около 300кБ С++ кода и 250кб старого Java кода, поэтому почти в любое место можно что-нибудь дописать и это что-то не вызовет 666 ошибок линковки. Ясно что на поздних стадиях невозможно будет работать с такой же скоростью.

Comment: @igumnov Хм, конечно все может быть, но я в последнее время понял, что написать ~400 строчек корректного `production` кода и отревьюить его за день - это очень непросто. Разумеется, речь не идет о коде тестов. Вы же пишете тесты, правда? :)

Comment: Мне вообще не ясно - о чем вы? Неужели кто-то действительно считает свою производительность по объему написанного кода?..

Стремиться нужно к качеству, а не к количеству.

Comment: я конечно этим не занимался.Но мне кажется что надо взять 2+ программиста КОТОРЫЕ НЕЗНАКОМЫ и дать каждому одну и тожу работу и посмотреть кто за сколько времени сделает.

Comment: Пятый вариант очень похож на утренний скрам.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Вариант 6.** Ежедневные 5-минутные тесты/головоломки для программистов. Вроде заданий из инструментальных тестов на навыки. Особенно с утра.

Плюсы:

1. объективная оценка хотя бы состояния человека перед началом дня;
2. прокачка мозга на програмирование, при регулярном ежедневном применении польза будет немала.

Минусы:

1. где брать тесты, постоянно новые, интересные, адекватные работе и навыкам. Возможно, тесты придётся покупать;
2. метрика оторвана от контекста работы.

Comment: Пошлют программеры такого начальника куда-подальше и правильно сделают.

Comment: С такими, что посылают, незачем работать. Пусть сидят в своей *опе мира всю жизнь.

Comment: @avp Ну этот вариант можно модифицировать. Ежедневные пятиминутные головомойки...

Comment: @alexlz, все толковые разбегутся. Что дальше будете делать?

Comment: так и представляю описание вакансии:

> бла-бла-бла
>
> - небольшой дружный коллектив
> - интересные задания
> - ежедневные пятиминутные головоломки

Comment: @avp, как обычно -- работать с теми, кто остался. (Не помню откуда): считается, что производительность квалифицированного программиста на порядок больше, чем у неквалифицированного. На выполнение работы надо 3 квалифицированных или 30 неквалифицированных программистов. Какой вариант выберет нормальный менеджер? (ответ 3 квалифицированных -- неправильный, ибо на кой ляд трём программистам ещё и манагер?)

Comment: Как по мне, уж кому кому, а программисту и без этого головоломок хватает с головой

Comment: @sergiks Сама идея может быть и не бесполезная (если договориться с командой и все будут строго "за"), но я бы не назвал это дело **метрикой.**

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать спасибо! На практике не пробовал, это лишь мысль. Имхо это именно метрика, т.к. оценивает по (типа,) эталонной шкале переменную величину. Неправильно назвал тесты головоломками. Скорее, именно тесты - на редко используемые функции или их параметры, на оптимальные алгоритмы — по аналогии с качественными онлайн-тестами на знание предметной области, как при интервью проходят, например.

Answer (score 10):

- [Хорошей общеизвестной метрики нет **(и вряд ли может быть),**](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/26596) но никто не мешает вам установить локальную для себя метрику продуктивности. Вы же подсознательно знаете, сделали вы сегодня больше, чем вчера, или меньше.
- Метрика производительности такого рода имеет смысл только в контексте проекта, а не разработчика. Рекомендую ознакомиться с информацией по поводу [Теории Ограничений](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_constraints) и по поводу ее распространения на `Agile` процессы.
- Фактически, вашим вариантом номер 5 вы частично переизобрели `Daily Scrum Meeting`.

Comment: Agile. А вот интересно, как ко всем этим Agile'ям относится "Крайслер"?

Comment: @alexlz Ну, теория ограничений и `Kanban` как ее технологическое воплощение радостно перекочевали в `IT` и прижились там. Вот так, грубо говоря, `Chrysler` и `Toyota` относятся к `Agile`.

Comment: Странно. После грандиозного провала Кента Бека с его XPерами...

Comment: @alexlz А где провал? Кент написал книжки по `XP` и рефакторингу и сейчас руководит своей консалтерской фирмой. Или я про что-то не в курсе?

Comment: Это было в давно, в прошлом тысячелетии... Проект C3(Crysler Comprehensive Compensation System) http://www.avocallc.com/downloads/ExtremeProgramming.pdf

Answer (score 6):

В нашей команде уже достаточно давно используется следующая схема:

Команда разделена на группы по 3-4 человека, в каждой группе есть главный (обычно более опытный сотрудник). Его задачи:

- раздача и контроль выполнения
  заданий, он тесно связан с процессом
  разработки (практически каждой задачи
  в его группе), поэтому в курсе
  прогресса
- review документации и кода
- оценка качества выполнения
  задач и эффективности членов его
  группы. Тесное взаимодействие людей
  одной группы практически гарантирует
  адекватные оценки со стороны лидера
  группы.

Лидеры групп репортят менеджеру команды. Последний не занимается решением технических вопросов, это обязанности "лидеров групп", его основные обязанности - это решение организационных вопросов.

т.е. наша схема склоняется к **варианту 3**

Answer (score 2):

Абсолютную шкалу построить невозможно. Не существует идеального программиста, ритм работы которого на любой задаче был бы оптимальным с точки зрения как скорости разработки, так и качества кода. Но это не значит, что производительность вообще не поддаётся измерению. Я использую для этого относительную метрику.

Перед началом каждого участка работы я, исходя из опыта, делаю более-менее реалистичные предположения о том, когда закончу, а после сравниваю их с реально затраченным временем. Если в процессе не возникло никаких форс-мажоров, но была существенная задержка, то значит производительность была низкой. Количество лишних часов красноречиво говорит о том, насколько низкой. Но бывает и наоборот. Задача решается быстрее, чем планировалось, и при этом я ясно понимаю, что решил задачу именно так, как и планировал - ничего в процессе не упростил. В этом случае я делаю вывод о том, что мне нужно пересмотреть собственные представления о своих возможностях в лучшую сторону - в действительности я круче, чем думаю о себе.

Comment: @Shamov, Вы эти сравнения проводите до умножения первоначальной оценки на три?

Как хорошо известно в реальной жизни время, необходимое для получения программы равно времени обещанному разработчиком, умноженному как минимум на три.

Comment: @avp Не столько "до", сколько вообще отдельно. Умножение на три - это менеджерское правило. Оно связано с тем, что после разработки есть ещё этапы отладки/тестирования и внедрения. Отладка - это вообще иррациональный процесс. Анализировать его можно только статистически (по опыту). А внедрение от меня почти не зависит. Так что измерить производительность я могу только на участке работы, который длится до появления версии, которая "теоретически должна работать".

Comment: @Shamov - "...исходя из опыта, делаю более-менее реалистичные предположения..." и как часто у вас получалось? :)

"сли в процессе не возникло никаких форс-мажоров, но была существенная задержка" никак не могу с этим согласится, если возникла задержка значит вы чего-то не знали, либо у вас что-то не получалось, ни от первого ни, тем более, от второго - никто не застрахован и, на мой взгляд, таким образом можно измерить только "вложился в сроки или нет"

Comment: "Оно связано с тем, что после разработки есть ещё этапы отладки/тестирования" либо вы работает над чем-то элементарным, либо вы гений, либо безнадежный оптимист :)

Comment: Обычно получается нормально предсказывать. Особенно на большом интервале, когда есть возможность внутреннего маневра: подзадачу, которая резко начинает снижать предполагаемый ритм, откладываю на конец... в конце её делать как-то легче - многое уже сделано, осталось совсем чуть-чуть добить.

Comment: "внутреннего маневра" т.е. костыля? а, ну если так, то, тогда - да.

"осталось совсем чуть-чуть ***добить***" т.е. вы задачу не решаете, а бьете? :)

Comment: Да, действительно. Получается, что я осмысляю этот процесс в терминах аналитической стратегии. В ней маневр - это основной инструмент преобразования стратегической позиции в более выигрышную. А слово "добить" отлично согласуется с термином "вторая критическая точка операции", который обозначает момент, когда выигрыш уже неизбежен, но чтобы он стал реальностью, предстоит проделать ещё много работы. Неопределённость в том, как именно программа будет сделана, уже преодолена, но ещё нужно отладить и внедрить.